# How do I use the same Visualforce page to override view, new, and edit buttons on custom object

Tags: visualforce, button-overrides

I have a custom Visualforce page for a custom object.  I have overriden the `new`, `edit`, and `view` buttons to point to this page.  I would like to dynamically change the look of the page based on what mode the user is in.

For example, show an `<apex:inputField />` when they are editing, but an `<apex:outputField />` when viewing:

```
<apex:outputField value="{!MyCustomObject__c.Field1}" rendered="{!pageMode == 'view'}" />
<apex:inputField value="{!MyCustomObject__c.Field1}" rendered="{!pageMode == 'edit'}" />
```

I would also use this property to set the `mode` attribute of my `<apex:pageBlock />`

Is there a good way to do this using a button override?  I do not want to create custom buttons and use URL parameters if I can avoid it.

Comment: This is a very good question. My initial response was to set the page attribute "readOnly" to true, but you would need to do that in your controller extension and I don't know how to evaluate what context "view, edit, etc" the page is in. I'd guess that if you do an override you can see if the url ends with /e for edit, etc and do that. But just a guess.

Comment: You could also create two separate pages, one for view and one for edit. It would be easier to maintain with two separate pages as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will lead to **a lot** of conditionally rendered tags. You might consider having separate page for "view" and separate for "new/edit" but use same controller extension if you really want.

But if you're determined... You can look at the URL that was used to navigate to your page and combine it with presence of Id in the standard controller.

I've called my page `override` and used Opportunity as the test object.

```
New: /apex/override?retURL=%2F006%2Fo&save_new=1&sfdc.override=1
View: /apex/override?id=0067000000AH3ME&sfdc.override=1
Edit: /apex/override?id=0067000000AH3ME&retURL=%2F006%3Ffcf%3D00B70000005pFQv%26rolodexIndex%3D-1%26page%3D1&sfdc.override=1
```

Something like this should work, at least until SF decides to rename/remove the `retUrl` param (unlikely I'd say... Especially than on viewing there's rarely something to cancel or "on success return to... where?").

```
public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardController ctrl){
    Id i = ctrl.getId();
    Map<String,String> parameters = ApexPages.currentPage().parameters();
    if(i == null){
        System.debug('new');
    } else if(parameters.contains('retUrl')){
        System.debug('edit');
    } else {
        System.debug('view');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  This does work.  However, if I'm going to have to check url parameters, I may as well make custom buttons so I can control the values and not have to worry about Salesforce changing a behavior.