# How to edite and view your feilds?

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, force.com

I want to insert a command button called Edit in my view page. All fields are in output mode, and when I click on the Edit button I want to type on them or make changes. (In my Scenario inlineEdit does not work). Can anybody please help me. Thanks

Comment: I add a edit button it does not work the way i want. I want to edit all my output field when i click the edit. It should in the same page and should activate the output fields into input field. So i can type


<apex:commandButton value="Edit2" action="{!URLFOR($Action.Product_Brief__c.Edit,Product_Brief__c.Id)}"/>

This is not the way i want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you would have to use a boolean in your controller which controls if the fields can be edited or not :

In your controller :

```
public Boolean bEditMode {
  get {
    if(bEditMode == null) {
      bEditmode = false;
    }
    return bEditMode;
  }
  set;
}

public PageReference doToggleEditMode() {
  bEditMode = !bEditMode;
  return null;
}

public PageReference doSave() {
  try {
    // Do your stuff to save your record
    doToggleEditMode();
  }
  catch(Exception ex) {
    // Handle error
  }

  return null;
}
```

In your VFPage :

```
<apex:outputPanel id="myPanel">

  <apex:commandButton action="{!doToggleEditMode}" value="Edit" reRender="myPanel" rendered="{!NOT(bEditMode)}" />
  <apex:commandButton action="{!doSave}" value="Save" reRender="myPanel" rendered="{!bEditMode}" />

  <apex:outputText value="{!someVar}" rendered="{!NOT(bEditMode)}" />
  <apex:inputText value="{!someVar}" rendered="{!bEditMode}" />

</apex:outputPanel>
```

I think that would do the job.
Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have done so many thing but does not work the way i want. I will try this one and let you know. Once again thanks.

Comment: Hey Julien Gaïotto,
It gives me a error "Error: justing Compile Error: Non-void method might not return a value or might have statement after a return statement."

Comment: public class justing {

    public Boolean bEditMode {
      get {
        if(bEditMode == null) {
          bEditmode = false;
            }
    return bEditMode;
      }
          set;
    }

    public PageReference doToggleEditMode() {
      bEditMode = !bEditMode;
    }
    
    public PageReference doSave() {
      try {
        // Do your stuff to save your record
        
        doToggleEditMode();
      }
      catch(Exception ex) {
        // Handle error
      }
    }
    
    public justing(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }
}

Comment: Ooops completely forgot to return null in the doToggleEditMode and doSave methods :/
I edited my post so that it is correct know

Comment: Hey Thank you very much. I think this the way i want it. Your the best. Once again thank you very much.

Comment: Hey Julien, I have a another problem.  If I have two view page I do I connect each other with this code. I mean when I click edit I would be able to edit both page and save. Do you have any idea? Thanks

Comment: I have a another problem. If I have two view page how do I connect each page with this code. I mean when I click edit I would be able to edit both page and save. Do you have any idea? Thanks –